# How to change hint text size for AndroidX SearchView?

Tags: android, androidx, searchview

I have tried these approaches which did not work -

**Approach 1:**

```
    val searchView = binding.mSearchView
    val linearLayout1 = searchView.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
    val linearLayout2 = linearLayout1.getChildAt(2) as LinearLayout
    val linearLayout3 = linearLayout2.getChildAt(1) as LinearLayout
    val autoComplete = linearLayout3.getChildAt(0) as AutoCompleteTextView
    autoComplete.textSize = 12f
```

**Approach 2:**

```
    <string name="search_hint"><font size="12">My hint string</font></string>   
 
    val searchSrcTextId = resources.getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, 
    null)
    val searchEditText = binding.mSearchView.findViewById<View>(searchSrcTextId) as 
    EditText
    searchEditText.hint = getString(R.string.search_hint)
```

This gives Null Pointer exception on line 3.

**Approach 3:**

```
<string name="search_hint"><font size="12">My hint string</font></string>

binding.mSearchView.queryHint = getString(R.string.search_hint)
Or
binding.mSearchView.queryHint = getText(R.string.search_hint)
```

**Approach 4:**

```
binding.mSearchView.queryHint = Html.fromHtml("<small><small> 
<small>"+getString(R.string.hint)
+ "</small></small></small>")
```

I want to change queryHint text size to 12sp of my androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.

Please help, i have tried everything i could, but not able to do it.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Hint will take the same text size as text . So you have few options here Use Spannable as Hint with RelativeSizeSpan or you can handle the text Size inside text Change listener. Something [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107032/how-to-change-hint-text-size-without-changing-the-text-size-in-edittext).

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link [How to set SearchView TextSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535176/how-to-set-searchview-textsize)

You could do these using code

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(2);
LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(1);
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) linearLayout3.getChildAt(0);
autoComplete.setTextSize(60);
```

Here is another solution

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
AutoCompleteTextView search_text = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
search_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
search_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, search_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_small));
```